# RosJava Tutorial Integration / Multiple Listeners

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem with topic publisher/subscriber integration in RosJava when using the rosjava version of RosCore. I can execute the following test successfully where multiple subscribers attach to a publisher.

```
public void testOnePublisherToManySubscriber() throws InterruptedException {
        nodeConfiguration.setNodeName("publisher");
        Node publisherNode = nodeFactory.newNode(nodeConfiguration);

        CountDownPublisherListener<org.ros.message.std_msgs.String> publisherListener =
            CountDownPublisherListener.newDefault();
        Publisher<org.ros.message.std_msgs.String> publisher =
            publisherNode.newPublisher("foo", "std_msgs/String");
        publisher.addListener(publisherListener);

        final org.ros.message.std_msgs.String helloMessage = new org.ros.message.std_msgs.String();
        helloMessage.data = "Hello, ROS!";

        final CountDownLatch messageReceived = new CountDownLatch(1);
        nodeConfiguration.setNodeName("subscriber");
        Node subscriberNode = nodeFactory.newNode(nodeConfiguration);

        CountDownSubscriberListener<org.ros.message.std_msgs.String> subscriberListener =
            CountDownSubscriberListener.newDefault();
        
        CountDownSubscriberListener<org.ros.message.std_msgs.String> subscriberListener2 =
                CountDownSubscriberListener.newDefault();
        
        Subscriber<org.ros.message.std_msgs.String> subscriber1 =
            subscriberNode.newSubscriber("foo", "std_msgs/String");
        subscriber1.addMessageListener(new MessageListener<org.ros.message.std_msgs.String>() {
          @Override
          public void onNewMessage(org.ros.message.std_msgs.String message) {
            assertEquals(helloMessage, message);
            messageReceived.countDown();
          }
        });
        subscriber1.addSubscriberListener(subscriberListener);
        
        Subscriber<org.ros.message.std_msgs.String> subscriber2 =
                subscriberNode.newSubscriber("foo", "std_msgs/String");
            subscriber2.addMessageListener(new MessageListener<org.ros.message.std_msgs.String>() {
              @Override
              public void onNewMessage(org.ros.message.std_msgs.String message) {
                assertEquals(helloMessage, message);
                messageReceived.countDown();
              }
            });
            subscriber2.addSubscriberListener(subscriberListener2);

        assertTrue(publisherListener.awaitMasterRegistrationSuccess(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        assertTrue(subscriberListener.awaitMasterRegistrationSuccess(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

        RepeatingPublisher<org.ros.message.std_msgs.String> repeatingPublisher =
            new RepeatingPublisher<org.ros.message.std_msgs.String>(publisher, helloMessage, 1000,
                executorService);
        repeatingPublisher.start();

        assertTrue(messageReceived.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

        repeatingPublisher.cancel();
        publisher.shutdown();
        subscriber1.shutdown();
        subscriber2.shutdown();
      }
```

However, if I fire up a RosCore on my own with something like:

```
  public static void main(String[] argv){
        RosCore core;
        if(argv.length == 1)
            core = newPublic(Integer.valueOf(argv[0]));
        else
            core = newPublic(11311);
        
        core.start();
      }
```

And then I use RosRun to execute the Talker node, it registers successfully. But then if I attempt to start multiple listeners an after the first fail. Subsequently... other pub/sub features fail to work properly. For example, starting a listener prior to a publisher. What am I doing wrong?

I'm executing the code in Eclipse on Windows, where I execute RosRun and then pass the package as an argument. After executing the second listener I get the following from RosCore:

```
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:11 PM org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer start
INFO: Starting master server.
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:20 PM org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer registerPublisher
INFO: Registering publisher: PublisherIdentifier<SlaveIdentifier</talker, http://127.0.0.1:55060>, TopicIdentifier</chatter>>
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:20 PM org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer publisherUpdate
INFO: Publisher update: /chatter
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:20 PM org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer registerPublisher
INFO: Registering publisher: PublisherIdentifier<SlaveIdentifier</talker, http://127.0.0.1:55060>, TopicIdentifier</rosout>>
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:20 PM org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer publisherUpdate
INFO: Publisher update: /rosout
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:26 PM org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer registerPublisher
INFO: Registering publisher: PublisherIdentifier<SlaveIdentifier</Listener1, http://127.0.0.1:55070>, TopicIdentifier</rosout>>
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:26 PM org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer publisherUpdate
INFO: Publisher update: /rosout
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:26 PM org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer registerSubscriber
INFO: Registering subscriber: SubscriberIdentifier<SlaveIdentifier</Listener1, http://127.0.0.1:55070>, TopicIdentifier</chatter>>
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:37 PM org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer registerSubscriber
INFO: Registering subscriber: SubscriberIdentifier<SlaveIdentifier</Listener1, http://127.0.0.1:55088>, TopicIdentifier</chatter>>
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:37 PM org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer addSlave
WARNING: Existing slave SlaveIdentifier</Listener1, http://127.0.0.1:55070> will be shutdown.
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:37 PM org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer registerPublisher
INFO: Registering publisher: PublisherIdentifier<SlaveIdentifier</Listener1, http://127.0.0.1:55088>, TopicIdentifier</rosout>>
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:37 PM org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer addSlave
WARNING: Existing slave SlaveIdentifier</Listener1, http://127.0.0.1:55070> will be shutdown.
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:37 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The server 127.0.0.1 failed to respond
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:37 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:37 PM org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcErrorLogger log
SEVERE: Failed to invoke method registerSubscriber in class org.ros.internal.node.xmlrpc.MasterXmlRpcEndpointImpl: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
org.apache.xmlrpc.common.XmlRpcInvocationException: Failed to invoke method registerSubscriber in class org.ros.internal.node.xmlrpc.MasterXmlRpcEndpointImpl: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.invoke(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.execute(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:106)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServerWorker.execute(XmlRpcServerWorker.java:46)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServer.execute(XmlRpcServer.java:86)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcStreamServer.execute(XmlRpcStreamServer.java:200)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.Connection.run(Connection.java:208)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.util.ThreadPool$Poolable$1.run(ThreadPool.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at org.ros.internal.node.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClientFactory$1.invoke(XmlRpcClientFactory.java:157)
    at $Proxy0.shutdown(Unknown Source)
    at org.ros.internal.node.client.SlaveClient.shutdown(SlaveClient.java:62)
    at org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer.addSlave(MasterServer.java:169)
    at org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer.registerSubscriber(MasterServer.java:218)
    at org.ros.internal.node.xmlrpc.MasterXmlRpcEndpointImpl.registerSubscriber(MasterXmlRpcEndpointImpl.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.invoke(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:115)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcCommonsTransport.writeRequest(XmlRpcCommonsTransport.java:227)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:151)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker$1.run(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:80)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at org.ros.internal.node.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClientFactory$1.invoke(XmlRpcClientFactory.java:157)
    at $Proxy0.shutdown(Unknown Source)
    at org.ros.internal.node.client.SlaveClient.shutdown(SlaveClient.java:62)
    at org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer.addSlave(MasterServer.java:169)
    at org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer.registerSubscriber(MasterServer.java:218)
    at org.ros.internal.node.xmlrpc.MasterXmlRpcEndpointImpl.registerSubscriber(MasterXmlRpcEndpointImpl.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.invoke(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.execute(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:106)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServerWorker.execute(XmlRpcServerWorker.java:46)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServer.execute(XmlRpcServer.java:86)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcStreamServer.execute(XmlRpcStreamServer.java:200)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.Connection.run(Connection.java:208)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.util.ThreadPool$Poolable$1.run(ThreadPool.java:68)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcCommonsTransport.writeRequest(XmlRpcCommonsTransport.java:227)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:151)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker$1.run(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:80)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

From the second listener I get:

```
   Loading node class: org.ros.tutorials.pubsub.Listener
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:37 PM org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar callMaster
SEVERE: Exception caught while communicating with master.
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:37 PM org.ros.internal.node.topic.DefaultSubscriber$1 onMasterRegistrationFailure
INFO: Subscriber registration failed: Subscriber<TopicDefinition<TopicIdentifier</chatter>, MessageDefinition<sensor_msgs/NavSatFix, 2d3a8cd499b9b4a0249fb98fd05cfa48>>>
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:41 PM org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar callMaster
SEVERE: Exception caught while communicating with master.
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:41 PM org.ros.internal.node.topic.DefaultPublisher$1 onMasterRegistrationFailure
INFO: Publisher registration failed: Publisher<PublisherDefinition<PublisherIdentifier<SlaveIdentifier</Listener1, http://127.0.0.1:55088>, TopicIdentifier</rosout>>, TopicDefinition<TopicIdentifier</rosout>, MessageDefinition<rosgraph_msgs/Log, acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb>>>>
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:46 PM org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar callMaster
SEVERE: Exception caught while communicating with master.
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:46 PM org.ros.internal.node.topic.DefaultSubscriber$1 onMasterRegistrationFailure
INFO: Subscriber registration failed: Subscriber<TopicDefinition<TopicIdentifier</chatter>, MessageDefinition<sensor_msgs/NavSatFix, 2d3a8cd499b9b4a0249fb98fd05cfa48>>>
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:50 PM org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar callMaster
SEVERE: Exception caught while communicating with master.
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:50 PM org.ros.internal.node.topic.DefaultPublisher$1 onMasterRegistrationFailure
INFO: Publisher registration failed: Publisher<PublisherDefinition<PublisherIdentifier<SlaveIdentifier</Listener1, http://127.0.0.1:55088>, TopicIdentifier</rosout>>, TopicDefinition<TopicIdentifier</rosout>, MessageDefinition<rosgraph_msgs/Log, acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb>>>>
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:55 PM org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar callMaster
SEVERE: Exception caught while communicating with master.
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:55 PM org.ros.internal.node.topic.DefaultSubscriber$1 onMasterRegistrationFailure
INFO: Subscriber registration failed: Subscriber<TopicDefinition<TopicIdentifier</chatter>, MessageDefinition<sensor_msgs/NavSatFix, 2d3a8cd499b9b4a0249fb98fd05cfa48>>>
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:59 PM org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar callMaster
SEVERE: Exception caught while communicating with master.
Jan 17, 2012 5:02:59 PM org.ros.internal.node.topic.DefaultPublisher$1 onMasterRegistrationFailure
INFO: Publisher registration failed: Publisher<PublisherDefinition<PublisherIdentifier<SlaveIdentifier</Listener1, http://127.0.0.1:55088>, TopicIdentifier</rosout>>, TopicDefinition<TopicIdentifier</rosout>, MessageDefinition<rosgraph_msgs/Log, acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb>>>>
Jan 17, 2012 5:03:04 PM org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar callMaster
SEVERE: Exception caught while communicating with master.
```

Some more information...

I added another test where I use the standard publisher/subscribers.

public void testOnePublisherToManySubscriberNoLatch()
throws InterruptedException {
nodeConfiguration.setNodeName("publisher");
Node publisherNode = nodeFactory.newNode(nodeConfiguration);

```
final Publisher<org.ros.message.std_msgs.String> publisher = publisherNode
        .newPublisher("foo", "std_msgs/String");

final org.ros.message.std_msgs.String msg = new org.ros.message.std_msgs.String();

publisherNode.executeCancellableLoop(new CancellableLoop() {
    private int sequenceNumber;

    @Override
    protected void setup() {
        sequenceNumber = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void loop() throws InterruptedException {

        msg.data = "Hello! " + sequenceNumber;

        publisher.publish(msg);
        sequenceNumber++;
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
});

nodeConfiguration.setNodeName("subscriber1");
Node subscriberNode1 = nodeFactory.newNode(nodeConfiguration);

Subscriber<org.ros.message.std_msgs.String> subscriber1 = subscriberNode1
        .newSubscriber("foo", "std_msgs/String");
subscriber1
        .addMessageListener(new MessageListener<org.ros.message.std_msgs.String>() {
            @Override
            public void onNewMessage(
                    org.ros.message.std_msgs.String message) {
                System.out.println("Listener1:" + message.data);
            }
        });

nodeConfiguration.setNodeName("subscriber2");
Node subscriberNode2 = nodeFactory.newNode(nodeConfiguration);
Subscriber<org.ros.message.std_msgs.String> subscriber2 = subscriberNode2
        .newSubscriber("foo", "std_msgs/String");
subscriber2
        .addMessageListener(new MessageListener<org.ros.message.std_msgs.String>() {
            @Override
            public void onNewMessage(
                    org.ros.message.std_msgs.String message) {
                System.out.println("Listener2:" + message.data);
            }
        });

subscriber1.shutdown();
subscriber2.shutdown();
publisher.shutdown();
```

}
This works as desired. Is it somehow related to the node configuration / hostname resolution? I don't have these issues if I use the regular rosmaster in linux.

Running the same test, but with a CPP publisher and a CPP listener on another host in addition to the two subscribers on the same host as the master, I get the following errors:

```
Jan 17, 2012 6:15:04 PM org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer registerPublisher
INFO: Registering publisher: PublisherIdentifier<SlaveIdentifier</subscriber2, http://192.168.1.113:56473>, TopicIdentifier</rosout>>
Jan 17, 2012 6:15:04 PM org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer publisherUpdate
INFO: Publisher update: /rosout
Jan 17, 2012 6:15:04 PM org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcErrorLogger log
SEVERE: Failed to invoke method registerPublisher in class org.ros.internal.node.xmlrpc.MasterXmlRpcEndpointImpl: 
org.apache.xmlrpc.common.XmlRpcInvocationException: Failed to invoke method registerPublisher in class org.ros.internal.node.xmlrpc.MasterXmlRpcEndpointImpl: 
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.invoke(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.execute(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:106)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServerWorker.execute(XmlRpcServerWorker.java:46)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServer.execute(XmlRpcServer.java:86)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcStreamServer.execute(XmlRpcStreamServer.java:200)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.Connection.run(Connection.java:208)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.util.ThreadPool$Poolable$1.run(ThreadPool.java:68)
Caused by: org.ros.exception.RemoteException: 
    at org.ros.internal.node.response.Response.fromListChecked(Response.java:115)
    at org.ros.internal.node.client.SlaveClient.publisherUpdate(SlaveClient.java:119)
    at org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer.publisherUpdate(MasterServer.java:195)
    at org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer.registerPublisher(MasterServer.java:259)
    at org.ros.internal.node.xmlrpc.MasterXmlRpcEndpointImpl.registerPublisher(MasterXmlRpcEndpointImpl.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.invoke(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:115)
    ... 6 more
Caused by:
org.ros.exception.RemoteException: 
    at org.ros.internal.node.response.Response.fromListChecked(Response.java:115)
    at org.ros.internal.node.client.SlaveClient.publisherUpdate(SlaveClient.java:119)
    at org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer.publisherUpdate(MasterServer.java:195)
    at org.ros.internal.node.server.MasterServer.registerPublisher(MasterServer.java:259)
    at org.ros.internal.node.xmlrpc.MasterXmlRpcEndpointImpl.registerPublisher(MasterXmlRpcEndpointImpl.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.invoke(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.execute(ReflectiveXmlRpcHandler.java:106)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServerWorker.execute(XmlRpcServerWorker.java:46)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcServer.execute(XmlRpcServer.java:86)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.server.XmlRpcStreamServer.execute(XmlRpcStreamServer.java:200)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.webserver.Connection.run(Connection.java:208)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.util.ThreadPool$Poolable$1.run(ThreadPool.java:68)

Jan 17, 2012 6:15:04 PM org.ros.internal.node.client.Registrar callMaster
SEVERE: Exception caught while communicating with master.
Jan 17, 2012 6:15:04 PM org.ros.internal.node.topic.DefaultPublisher$1 onMasterRegistrationFailure
INFO: Publisher registration failed: Publisher<PublisherDefinition<PublisherIdentifier<SlaveIdentifier</subscriber2, http://192.168.1.113:56473>, TopicIdentifier</rosout>>, TopicDefinition<TopicIdentifier</rosout>, MessageDefinition<rosgraph_msgs/Log, acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb>>>>
Listener2:hello world 1733
```

Looks like perhaps a RosOut issue...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12667/rosjava-tutorial-integration-/-multiple-listeners/) by [stevefturner](https://answers.ros.org/users/792/stevefturner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-01-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevefturner](https://answers.ros.org/users/792/stevefturner/) on 2012-01-18**:
I've narrowed it down to a the publisherUpdate call in SlaveClient. If I attempt to register two publishers on the same topic on two different hosts, I get the failure: org.apache.xmlrpc.common.XmlRpcInvocationException: Failed to invoke method registerPublisher in class org.ros.internal.node.xmlrpc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this is a bug in the current rosjava implementation of roscore at head. The released version of rosjava should not have this problem. We're working to resolve this at head.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2